# Web screen wizard creation for training

Tags: web-applications, demo

---

Want to created Training wizard for the Web application pages.

Have created web application. Users need Interactive training wizard. In the training user will give inputs. Based on the inputs the training wizard should move further.

Example : In the Webscreen there is a button in the training wizard once user click on button then only training wizard should go to the next step.

Is there any tools to create this type of training wizards.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways Ram. You would go for coding or just drag-and-drop option? I suggest you go for coding as you will have more control on it.

Comment: Looking for Training video. Number of application screen shots moving based on the user inputs. Like one screen Click here indication User should click on particular highlighted area then it moves to next screen. if user click on out of highlighted area error should popup. Any tool name or any other help

Comment: @Ram You can try [NinjaMock](https://ninjamock.com/). It is a useful application online for application testing. My suggestion is you upload your Web pages screenshot there and make button based on your design. Give it a try. :D